# ReactiveX Observable Execution: Who Executes What and How are the Callbacks Chosen?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactivex

A couple of questions on intricacies of RxJS I still do not understand, after having spent a few days devouring the documentation.

**Known Information**

- When an `Observer` subscribes to an `Observable`, the `Observable` is executed

  - Referred to as an "Observable Execution" in the docs
- An "Observable Execution" means that an `Observable` delivers values (aka. notifications) to an `Observer`

  - The delivered values can be `next`, `error` or `complete`
  - Multiple next values are allowed, but only one `error` or `complete`
- An `Observer` defines three callbacks: `next`, `error`, `complete`
- One of the three callbacks will execute when the `Observer` receives a value from the `Observable`

**My Questions**

- `subscribe` tells the `Observable` to start delivering values to its Observer. Is it the `Observable` that also *executes* the callbacks in the `Observer`? Or does the `Observer` execute its own callbacks, when it receives a value from the `Observable` (which does not start delivering until the `Observer` subscribes)?

  - I am trying to understand who executes what. Since it is the callbacks (in the `Observer`) that are executed, it is confusing that they call it "Observable Execution", as opposed to "Observer Execution" or "Callback Execution"
- How does the `Observer` know which of the three callbacks to execute, when it receives a value from the `Observable` it subscribes to? Does it just look at the type of the value, and if it is a JavaScript error, it will use the `error` callback, if it is empty it will use `complete`, and otherwise it will use `next`?

Comment: [Learning Observable By Building Observable](https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87)

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting, but does not address the questions unfortunately.

Comment: From memory, I believe it does - or I've complete misunderstood the question. An observable is at its core a function that is passed an observer which it - **the observable** - calls. The observer is created by the `subscribe` implementation using the `next`, `error` and `complete` handlers, or the subscriber that's passed to `subscribe`. Observables sources of **pushed** values; the observer is called directly by the observable and just forwards the calls to its `next`, `error` and `complete` to the handlers, etc.

Comment: @cartant I played around with the author's JSBin a bit, and as you suggest, the `Observable` is passed an `Observer` object. That `Observer` object can have three functions defined in it (`next`, `error`, `complete`). I say "can have", because it does not need to have all three (RxJS docs). Then, the `Observable` just assigns an invocation of those three methods to three new properties on the underlying source. The underlying source will then execute the three callbacks, as long as the property is defined in the `Observable`. So, in short, the `Observable` executes the `Observer`'s callbacks.

Comment: Yep, but you will find that the observer the observable receives will always have `next`, `error` and `complete` methods, as the observer will have been created by `subscribe` - using the (optional) callbacks it receives. I will point you to the source if you like - later, though, 'cause I'm on mobile right now.

Comment: @cartant It is therefore confusing (at least to me) that the RxJS docs talk about `Observable Execution`, but never about `Observer callback execution`. Yes, an `Observable` is executed when it is subscribed to, but the callbacks inside the `Observer` are executed by the `Observable`. Thus, there are two separate executions going on here, and that fact is not terribly clear in the docs.

Comment: @cartant Saw your reply after having posted my new comment :) From the docs: `Observers in RxJS may also be partial. If you don't provide one of the callbacks, the execution of the Observable will still happen normally, except some types of notifications will be ignored, because they don't have a corresponding callback in the Observer.` - Source: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observer

Comment: @cartant I was thinking of adding a full answer for the benefit of future visitors, including a code example. Would you like to type up a reply (given that you pointed me to the article), or should I? Thanks again for the discussion.

Comment: If you now understand it, by all means answer it yourself. Doing so is encouraged. The terms observer and subscriber are often used interchangeably - which can be confusing. From my point of view, [`subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Observable.ts#L192-L213) receives optional callbacks or a subscriber with optional callbacks and calls [`toSubscriber`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/util/toSubscriber.ts) to ensure that the observer received by the observable function has all of the callbacks.